# Is this the correct way to set state using react's useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I was looking into React hooks and wasn't sure how useState works with arrays. So I made a working example with 3 controlled inputs, fed by an array. It works but I was wondering if this is the correct/optimal way of doing this.

[Working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/lideebe/pen/ExgVQjJ?editors=1010)

```
const { useState } = React;

const InputAndButton = ({ tag, index, handleTagChange }) => (
  <div>
    <input value={tag} onChange={(e) => handleTagChange(e.target.value, index)} />
    <button type="button" onClick={() => handleTagChange('', index)}>&times;</button>
  </div>
)

function Tags(){
  const [ tags, setTags ] = useState(["", "", ""]);
  const handleTagChange = (value, index) => {
    // make copy of state
    const tagsCopy = [...tags];
    // change the [i] value to the new one given
    tagsCopy[index] = value;
    // set copy back as state
    setTags(tagsCopy);
  }
  return(
    <form>
      tags
      {tags.map((tag, i) => <InputAndButton tag={tag} index={i} handleTagChange={handleTagChange} key={i} />)}
    </form>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Tags />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Can anybody give me some feedback here?

Comment: Looks fine to me, though I'd personally prefer to use `.map` instead (avoids mutation entirely)

Comment: any reason why you are doing "useState(["","",""]) ? that is not how you do it. You just use "useState([])"

Comment: I initialize the state as an array with 3 empty fields because I use those to render out the inputs. It could set state to [] instead but that would require more code to render out 3 fields and check for each field if there's a corresponding value in state.